# What does the number mean after my function name in disassembly? e.g <do_magic+197>

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering, disassembly

When using the `disass` command to inspect a function which is called multiple times I see:

`0x804870b <do_magic+201>`
`0x80486ef <do_magic+173>`
`0x8048707 <do_magic+197>`

These are all after `jmp` or `jne` commands. I understand that the memory address specified is the one to jump to.

What is the number after the function name referring to e.g +201,+173 and +197?

Comment: Maybe it's the offset of the return address relative to the function address

Comment: It's exactly what it looks like: `do_magic+173` just means the address labelled "do_magic" plus 173 bytes.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker so does that mean do_magic+173 would be the equivalent of the memory address also specified?

Comment: Do the math: `do_magic` is apparently 0x8048642.

Comment: It's [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) which makes binary a lot easier by grouping 0/1 digits in sets of 4. If you want to understand assembly code, the sooner you get it the better. You've said that `do_magic` is the function name. The disassembler helpfully gives you the *branch* destination relative to the function start, as well as its actual address. Looking at the first and last of the three, the address differs by 4 and so does the offset. The offset is given in decimal though.

Comment: I agree with WV--until you're comfortable with the basic concepts of binary and hexadecimal notation, programming in assembly is going to be a problem. I didn't do the math manually (i.e. pen and paper), although I could have--I just opened up a command line in Python and typed "hex(0x0x804870b - 201)"

Comment: I'm not programming in Assembly, I'm reverse engineering it - I know that's hexadecimal I wasn't sure how to calculate it. I have now realised its the offset as also specified in the disass output. Thanks!

Comment: The offsets seen in backtraces are frequently in base-10.   Just to be confusing. Worth considering  both until you're sure

Comment: It's helpful service of your disassembler. The actual instruction only contains the address, e.g. `0x804870b`.

Comment: `disass` made me chuckle. I've just always used `disas`.